# Sheets - Formula to count against another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want to count how many CV's sent references are against the job references to see how many CV's were sent to each job and if any had none sent against it. I tried the COUNTIF formula but it wanted a certain word to look at where as mine is another cell/different refs

Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14uybbRel1dqU2PpLFO4Vz7mhoopfC932fQ-2_PNxYfg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you *manually* enter your ideal output scenario in the sample sheet so as for us to get a clear picture on whats your expectation here?!

Comment: I was more of expecting to see whats your ultimate output structure is like(not description-based), I mean are you looking to have countif values or a filtered list based on countif values?! You cited `PR-1110488` is in Job but not in CV; so `=countif(A:A,D3)` should give you the **0** value for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following-

```
=MAP(D3:INDEX(D3:D,COUNTA(D3:D)),LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(A:A,x)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D3:D), "",COUNTIF(A3:A, D3:D)))
```

Basically I understand that you want to count each job reference from the `Jobs` column in the `CV's Sent` column. If this is not the case, please share an example of the desired output.